# Facebook ,twitter and Linkedin integration with Full Functionality in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, twitter, linkedin-api

I have experience of integration of facebook and twitter api. But Its just feed post.
I want full Facebook application which shows friends list their messages and events.
And i want same thing for twitter and linkedin.
If any body have idea or code for this please give me link or post that.

Thanks

Comment: If you want the full feature set of facebook, twitter and linkedin wont it be simple to just use the browser?! Why would you need an app?

Comment: hi anand,but still i develpo app for facebook with general features like post message ,show friend list etc.. .I need to develop app because any body can use above discussed social sites through one app. And User can show all details related to social sites using one app.

Answer (score 2):

the API for Linkedin You can refer this  :

http://developer.linkedin.com/thread/1169?tstart=30

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIWebView to load twitter and facebook. It will let you exploit the entire functionality offered by these two Social networking sites. Though It's not impossible to build an application the way you want it to be but using webview will save your time as well as efforts. Since you are already aware of the FB and twitter integration so I am sure you are already aware as to what all we can do from iPhone application..viz.. Setting Status, reading POSTS etc.. I am not quite sure about Linkedin.. Just in case if you come across any solution for this let me also know about that.